# Render, view, annotate pdf files

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I wanna start a project in which I want to do the following scenario:

- opening an existing pdf file through c# winform,
- **display** pdf contents in the form,
  good quality and different zoom levels are welcomed!
- prepare some tools such as Highlight and Underline tools for user to do these **annotations**.
  (selecting text ability is necessary for this I think !)
- save annotated pdf file.
- some other options such as add note to file and search in the text are welcomed!

---

Note that I **shouldn't use any commercial component** such as PDFViewer4Net, PDFNet SDK, PDF rasterizer,...

So, is it possible !? ( or I should give up my job!! )

should I use any library ?

please help me, I really need it !

thanks in advance.

---

edit:

displaying pdf file should be just in winform, not in IE for example, beacause printing and saving pdf file to other places should be disabled !

Comment: It might be better to split this question into 5 different questions, since you're asking how to implement 5 separate features in a single question.

Comment: these questions are related to each other. solving one question without paying attention to others may be useless! for example opening pdf file without annotation tools is not complete(but can be helpful!) thanks

Comment: I'm removing iTextSharp as a tag and voting the question down because this question isn't suited for SO. Also saying "I shouldn't use any commercial component" in combination with a question like this (asking for a PDF viewer with plenty of value) is like spitting in people's face (but that may be a purely personal comment.)

Comment: See the answer by @jamesmus (it got an upvote from me). You're basically trying to find a way to use the IP generated by people such as Thomas Merz (PDFLib, which isn't free for the use you're planning), me (iText, not gratis for commercial use), and many other real developers. Such a question isn't suited for SO and on top of that the question is phrased in a way that could be considered as self-damaging for your reputation (fortunately for you, you didn't mention your name).

Answer (score 5):

In answer to the (slightly re-phrased) specific question: *...or should I give up my job?*:

Quite frankly, yes.

To clarify: this is such a 'please do my homework for me' style of question that it's difficult to know where to start with an answer.  But I will have a go anyway.  Given the constraints that you have placed on the solution (no commercial products) I suggest that you read the Portable Document Format specification (which is linked from [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) Wikipedia entry) and implement your own rendering library that supports the features you are looking for.